# magento payment gateway ccavenue not working in frontend

Tags: magento, payment-gateway

I download the ccavenue payment gateway module its working fine on megento 
back end but it's not show in front end.
I clear the cash and index refresh but it's not working.
Please help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure you have enabled CCAvenue as a payment gateway.
- Check file permissions of template/layout files
- CCAvenue mostly has encrypted module. You can contact them to get un-encrypted one. OR if you already have it, debug by doing echo-exit in model files for payment gateway.

Its difficult to analyze issue as there is no reference of what is the error you are getting but you can try above steps to check.